How to non-desctructively join meshes with shape keys on export?
I make models for use in Unity so I need to merge various objects on FBX export in my workflow.
So far I successfully used Geometry Nodes to perform my mesh baking tasks, however you cannot use any modifier on a mesh with shape keys.
I have a avatar with shape keys where I need to join a mesh after applying its modifiers. I want this operation to be done on export in a non-destructive way in a single click, preferably using the same Blender native export UI I use currently, but a script that adds an Export button is fine.
Do you have suggestions ?
